# Serial monitor implementation segmentation fault

Tags: c, serial-port

I have made a code to read the serialprint from an Arduino UNO and wish to use that to move the cursor in Linux Ubuntu 17.02. The code runs fine whenever it is run for 1 iteration.

My Arduino will print a code of the format 
    [0-1],xcord,ycord**
The star is padded so that the string is of length 12 
xcord and ycord take values in between 0 and 1023 
These values come from a joystick I wish I could be more specific on name or type of said joystick but it is not written on it any where 
Moreover I doubt the problem has anything to do with my Arduino side but rather on my c side

Any help will be appreciated

```
#define _BSD_SOURC
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

struct cord
{
    int sw;
    int x_axis;
    int y_axis;
 }; 
void mouseMove(struct cord s1)
{
    Display *displayMain = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if(displayMain == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore nell'apertura del Display !!!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //XWarpPointer(displayMain, None, None, 0, 0, 0, 0, s1.x_axis, s1.y_axis);

    XCloseDisplay(displayMain);
}
struct cord decode(char *buffer)
{
    struct cord s1;
   s1.sw=buffer[0]-'0';
   int i=2;
   s1.x_axis=0;
   s1.y_axis=0;
   while(buffer[i]!=',')
   {
       s1.x_axis=s1.x_axis*10+(buffer[i]-'0');
       i++; 
    }

   i++;
   while(buffer[i]!='*'||buffer[i]=='\0')
   {
       s1.y_axis=s1.y_axis*10+(buffer[i]-'0');
       i++;
   }

   s1.x_axis=-s1.x_axis+497;
   s1.y_axis=s1.y_axis-497;
   //printf("%d %d %d\n",s1.sw,s1.x_axis/50,s1.y_axis/50);
   return s1;
 }

char* arread(int fd)
 {
  ssize_t n;
  char* buf=(char *)malloc(128*sizeof(char));
  n = read(fd, buf, 128); 
  buf[n]='\0';
  //printf("%zd bytes got read...\n", n);
  //printf("\n%s\n", buf);
  return buf;
 }
int main()
{
 int fd;
 char *portname = "/dev/ttyACM1";
 if((fd = open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY))==-1)
 {
  close(fd);
  printf("error in opening Port");
 }
 else
 {
  struct termios toptions;
  if(tcgetattr(fd, &toptions)==0)
 {
   if(cfsetispeed(&toptions, B9600)==0)
    {
     if(cfsetospeed(&toptions, B9600)==0)
      {
       toptions.c_cflag &= (unsigned int)~PARENB;
       toptions.c_cflag &= (unsigned int)~CSTOPB;
       toptions.c_cflag &= (unsigned int)~CSIZE;
       toptions.c_cflag |= (unsigned int)CS8;
       toptions.c_cflag &= (unsigned int)~CRTSCTS;
       toptions.c_cflag |= (unsigned int)CREAD | (unsigned int)CLOCAL;
       toptions.c_iflag &= (unsigned int)~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
       toptions.c_lflag &= (unsigned int)~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
       toptions.c_oflag &= (unsigned int)~OPOST;
       toptions.c_cc[VMIN] = 12;
       toptions.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
       if(tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &toptions)==0)
        { 
         //int i=0;
         //while(i<5)
         //{
            mouseMove(decode(arread(fd)));
            //i++;
          //}
         }
       else 
         printf("error 4"); 
       }
   else
       printf("error 3");     
   }
  else printf("error 2");
 }
else 
   printf("error 1");
 }
}
```

This is the updated code i no longer get the error of segmentation fault however i keep on getting junk values as output . Also i dont know how it is printing as i blocked every printf that could do it.

For the value of the buffer this is the arduino code I used

```
const int SW_pin = 2; // digital pin connected to switch output
const int X_pin = 5; // analog pin connected to X output
const int Y_pin = 4; // analog pin connected to Y output
char buffer[12];
int x,n;
void setup() 
  {
   pinMode(SW_pin, INPUT);
   digitalWrite(SW_pin, HIGH);
   Serial.begin(9600);
  }
void loop() 
  {
   n=sprintf(buffer,"%d,%d,%d",digitalRead(SW_pin),analogRead(X_pin),analogRead(Y_pin));
   for(x=n;x<12;x++)
   buffer[x]='*';
   buffer[12]='\0';
   Serial.println(buffer);
   delay(500);
  }
```

Comment: You should check the return value of `open` before blindly using `fd`. You also should call `close` when you are done.

Comment: Is `buffer` guaranteed to have the format you describe? Otherwise you access memory out of bounds. `while(buffer[i]!=',')`. Can you print the contents of your buffer and trace what happens?

Comment: First of all, you need to learn how to format (indent) code.  Second, you need to check return codes for all syscalls.  Third, @MFisherKDX's first comment is on the right track.  Besides failing to close the port, your code would (re-)open the serial port on each iteration, which is foolish (especially with unnecessary **usleep()** and **tcflush()** to muck things up).

Comment: The posted code, compiled with `gcc` on linux 16.04 with the parameters: `-c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` results in many warnings about unused variables, missing prototypes, implicit conversions etc.  Strongly suggest fixing the warnings

Comment: this is a 'forever' loop: `while( buffer[i]!='*' || buffer[i]=='\0')`

Comment: what is: `/dev/ttyACM2`  Per the code, this is expected to be a serial port.  Serial ports are (normally) named with the pattern: `ttyS###`

Comment: @user3629249 1) can you please guide me with how I should solve the warnings thrown by your parameters because as I read online I couldnt find any help for this   2)The loop ends for sure it I get correct value the code is only run whithout the while(1) 3)the serial port was written on arduino IDE I just copy pasted it

Comment: opening a file that is already open scrambles the file control block.  Strongly suggest only opening the file one (and adjusting the parameters) at the beginning of `main()`, then pass the resulting file descriptor number to `arread()` as a `int` parameter.

Comment: regarding: `int n = read(fd, buf, 128);` the value in 'n' could be 0 or even less than 0.  The code needs to check for these return conditions and handle them properly.

Comment: Ok, how to correct the warnings:  1) removed unused variables from the code 2) cast the macros like `PARENB`  to the proper type (which is `unsigned int`) (there are several places where this needs to be done)  3) the returned type from `read()` is `ssize_t`, not `int`.  so declare the variable `n` as `ssize_t`.  then when printing that value us a format specifier, similar to `%ld`   Suggest re-organizing the code so `main()` is first function and supply prototypes for all the other functions before the `main()` function.

Comment: Note: the functions; `tcsetattr()` `tcgetattr()`, `tcflush()` `cfsetispeed()` all have returned values (type `int`) that indicate if the function was successful or not.  The code should be checking each of those returned values to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the call to `tcgetattr()` should have saved the resulting options to a `struct termios` variable.  then before exiting `main()` call `tcsetattr()` with the saved options, then call `close()` on `fd`

Comment: note: in general, global variables (portname and buf) is a bad idea.  suggest moving them to inside the function(s) that actually use them.

Comment: regarding: `printf("%d %d %d",s1.sw,s1.x_axis/50,s1.y_axis/50);`  output streams are buffered.  So to get immediate display of the data on the terminal, one of 4 events needs to happen.  1) the program exits. 2) the OS buffer overflows 3) a input operation is performed 4) the OS buffer is flushed by something like `fflush( stdout );` or by a  `\n` at the end of the format string: I.E. `"%d %d %d\n"`

Comment: why is the input buffer declared as 256 bytes but the call to `read()` is only asking for 128 bytes?  Note: `read()` does not NUL terminate the input char array, so should have a statement similar to: `buf[n] = '\0';`  (if the value 'n' is positive, see my earlier comment about checking that value.)

Comment: passing a complete struct is problematic, especially as the struct gets bigger.  Suggest declaring the struct in `main()` and passing around a pointer to that struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the code worked thanks a lot to @user3629249

```
#define _BSD_SOURC
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

struct cord
 {
  int sw;
  int x_axis;
  int y_axis;
 };
void mouseMove(struct cord* s1)
 {
  Display *displayMain = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  if(displayMain == NULL)
   {
    fprintf(stderr, "Errore nell'apertura del Display !!!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   //XWarpPointer(displayMain, None, None, 0, 0, 0, 0, s1.x_axis, s1.y_axis);

   XCloseDisplay(displayMain);
  }
  struct cord* decode(char *buffer)
   {
    struct cord* s1 = malloc(sizeof(struct cord));
    s1->sw=0;
    s1->x_axis=0;
    s1->y_axis=0;
    if(strcmp(buffer,"error")!=1)
    {  
     s1->sw=buffer[0]-'0';
     int i=2;
     while(buffer[i]!=',')
     {
       s1->x_axis=s1->x_axis*10+(buffer[i]-'0');
       i++; 
     }
    i++;
    while(buffer[i]!='*'||buffer[i]=='\0')
    {
      s1->y_axis=s1->y_axis*10+(buffer[i]-'0');
      i++;
    }

    s1->x_axis=-s1->x_axis+497;
    s1->y_axis=s1->y_axis-497;
    //printf("%d %d %d\n",s1.sw,s1.x_axis/50,s1.y_axis/50);
    }
     return s1; 
  }
 char* arread(int fd)
 {
  ssize_t n,n1;
  char* buf=(char *)malloc(128*sizeof(char));
  char*ch=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
  while(ch[0]!='\n')
 {
  n1=read(fd,ch,1);
 }
  n = read(fd, buf, 12); 
  buf[n]='\0';
  printf("\n%zd\n", n);
  printf("%s\n", buf);
  if(n>0) 
  {
   return buf;
  }
  else 
  {
   printf("error");
   return "error";
  }

  int main()
  {
   int fd;
   char *portname = "/dev/ttyACM0";
   fd = open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
   if(fd==-1)
   {
    close(fd);
    printf("erip");
   }
   else
   {
    struct termios toptions;
    if(tcgetattr(fd, &toptions)==0)
    {
     if(cfsetispeed(&toptions, B9600)==0)
      {
       if(cfsetospeed(&toptions, B9600)==0)
        {
         toptions.c_cflag &= (unsigned int)~PARENB;
         toptions.c_cflag &= (unsigned int)~CSTOPB;
         toptions.c_cflag &= (unsigned int)~CSIZE;
         toptions.c_cflag |= (unsigned int)CS8;
         toptions.c_cflag &= (unsigned int)~CRTSCTS;
         toptions.c_cflag |= (unsigned int)CREAD | (unsigned int)CLOCAL;
         toptions.c_iflag &= (unsigned int)~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
         toptions.c_lflag &= (unsigned int)~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
         toptions.c_oflag &= (unsigned int)~OPOST;
         toptions.c_cc[VMIN] = 12;
         toptions.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
         if(tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &toptions)==0)
         { 
          //int i=0;
          //while(i<5)
          //{
             mouseMove(decode(arread(fd)));
             //i++;
           //}
          }
      else 
         printf("error 4"); 
     }
   else
       printf("error 3");     
   }
  else printf("error 2");
 }
 else 
 printf("error 1");
}
}
```

In the end the part that was causing all the errors was the read function. I originally used carelessly without thinking what the serial monitor is actually printing right now and so i got junk values . However after a ch searching for a '\n' it worked like a charm